# JavaFX video encoding

Tags: flash, video, javafx, encoding

On [JavaFX's Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javafx)

> In May 2008 (...) Sun Also announced a
>   multi-year agreement with On2 
>   Technologies to bring comprehensive
>   video capabilities to the JavaFX 
>   product family using the company's
>   TrueMotion Video codec.

Do you know if it will include `encoding capabilities` for Webcam Video like Flash or just playback/streaming?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JavaFX API` just supports media playback at the moment (see here: [javafx.scene.media.MediaView](http://javafx.com/releases/preview1/docs/api/javafx.scene.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaView.html#)).  There might very well be mere Java APIs for encoding, however.